# Behavior of ArrayList<>().contains(Object obj)

Tags: java, arraylist

It's not actual problem it's more like a question. How exactly method `contains(Object obj)` checks if object exists in collection? I have simple sample that made me kind of confused.
I have two lists, first list `oldList = new ArrayList<FtpFileInfo>()` and second list `newList = new ArrayList<FtpFileInfo>()`
oldList contains something like that:

```
newone.txt
test.txt
test2.txt
```

and newList contains:

```
newone.txt
test.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

In simple for-each loop I check if any object from newList exists in oldList, and if not I put it to new list called outputList:

```
for(FtpFileInfo newFile : newList) {
    if(!oldList.contains(newFile)) {
        outputList.add(newFile.getFilename());
    }
}
```

And I suspect the output of this list should be:

```
test3.txt
```

but I get:

```
newone.txt
test.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

I've tried the same example but with String objects and everything works as I thought, so what is wrong with my example, or this behavior is caused by FtpFileInfo object?

Comment: Do you have implemented the method `equals` of `FtpFileInfo` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
How exactly method contains(Object obj) checks if object exists in collection?
```

Each and every implementation have implemented `contains()` method

In `ArrayList<>()`

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}
```

Then

```
 public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i])) // important 
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now you see you need to implement `equals()` correctly.

Solution.

Override `equals()` method correctly in `FtpFileInfo`

Comment: So, for all of types of objects I have to implement my own equals method? Those which is by default works only for strings? Am I understand this right?

Comment: @mlethys yes you have to override `equals()` method in all your custom class. In `Java` `String` they have implemented the `equals()` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @mlethys all the objects has equals method. but bydefault it will be checking the memory locaton of that object. which will never be equal for two objects instantiated in different places. So you have to write your own equals method

Comment: So I should override equals for FtpFileInfo object, right? But what should I do if it isn't my class? It's object type from spring-integration.
Edit: Should I extend FtpFileInfo class with my own one and then implement my own equals?

Comment: @mlethys you don't want to worry about 3rd party classes. If that class from trusted 3rd party like `spring` they already `override` `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Comment: Ok, it has but it doesn't work as expected as I've shown in example above.

Comment: @mlethys http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

From [Java docs for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to override the `FtpFileInfo.equals(Object)` method. By default it compares whether the two objects are at the same address in memory, not whether they represent the same thing.

Something like this will achieve the right result, but it wouldn't be the best way of doing it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof FtpFileInfo) && (toString().equals(obj.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Well, it would be nice but FtpFileInfo is object from spring-integration, not my own class.